# First click in child component is undefined in parent component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-component

I want to implement a "delete contact when clicked" in a simple contact manager app I'm making to learn React but it is very buggy.
The first time I click the item to delete it does nothing and when clicked another time it deletes the previous one. I'm new learning react and don't know why is this happening, someone can help?

```
const { useState } = React;

function AddPersonForm(props) {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setPerson(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    props.handleSubmit(person);
    setPerson("");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add new contact"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={person}
      />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function PeopleList(props) {
  const [person_, setPerson_] = useState("");
  function handleCLick(e) {
    setPerson_(e.target.textContent);
    props.handleCLick(person_);
  }

  return (
    <ul onClick={handleCLick}>
      {props.data.map((val, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{val}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function ContactManager(props) {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(props.data);

  function addPerson(name) {
    setContacts([...contacts, name]);
  }
  function removePerson(name_) {
    let filtered = contacts.filter(function (value) {
      return value != name_;
    });
    setContacts(filtered);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <AddPersonForm handleSubmit={addPerson} />
      <PeopleList data={contacts} handleCLick={removePerson} />
    </div>
  );
}
const contacts = ["James Smith", "Thomas Anderson", "Bruce Wayne"];

ReactDOM.render(
  <ContactManager data={contacts} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Having the `onClick` handler on the unordered list element seems a bit odd to me, but your issue a misunderstanding of when React state updates. React state updates are enqueued and *asynchronously* processed. In other words, when you enqueue the state update `setPerson_(e.target.textContent)` in `handleClick` in `PeopleList`, that `person_` hasn't updated on the next line `props.handleCLick(person_);`. You are using state that hasn't updated yet.

## Solution

Just send the `click` event object's value to the `props.handleClick` callback directly. You can also remove the local `person_` state.

```
function PeopleList(props) {
  function handleCLick(e) {
    props.handleCLick(e.target.textContent);
  }

  return (
    <ul onClick={handleCLick}>
      {props.data.map((val, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{val}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit first-click-in-child-component-is-undefined-in-parent-component-react]

Comment: Thanks! This delete <li> items functionality is only for learning purposes I'll do some buttons and improve the design in that items. Or do you mean it's better to do that behaviour in another way ?

Comment: @akerbeltz I meant that typically a delete/onClick handler would be attached to each list item, or element/component in each list item. Depends on UI design.

Comment: oh, I see.  I notice a lot of event delegations in javascript and was used to do that way but maybe in react it's different, I'll read more about that topic.